# How to script blender to quit after rendering is complete Mac OS10.13

Tags: python, scripting, osx

I've got a script that automatically renders and saves the render, but I'd also like to have Blender quit when the render and save is completed.  Since I will be running renders overnight, I'd prefer to have it shut off when finished.

I've checked out the alarm_and_shutdown script by Metelskiy and Nikitin, but it's for windows.

Any ideas?

Turns out that the command is `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()`

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. If you found a solution we encourage to post it as a self answer below. As a bonus you might get some reputation points

Comment: Recommend looking into  running from the command line. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workflows/command_line.html

Comment: Last time I posted as an answer I got reprimanded for not editing the post.  Confused now.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the command is bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()